# Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list' python pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am using `pandas (0.20.3)` and `python 3.5.3`

I have error like this

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'
```

I thought it is because of mysql doesn't understand 'nan' as mull.

According to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353732/python-pandas-write-to-sql-with-nan-values)

The problem was fixed in pandas 0.15.0

However I still have this error. is there something wrong with my cord??

Or where should I fix??

```
stocksDf = pd.read_csv('companys.csv', names=['name','place'])

for i,row in stocksDf.iterrows():
    sql = "insert into CompanyUs(name,place) VALUES(%s,%s)" 
    data = (row['name'],row['place'])
    cur.execute(sql,data)
    pprint("Company Write : %s" % row['name'])
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: You are not using `to_sql` from `pandas`, but `execute` from other MYSQL API, so it is not the same situation with the referred article and is not related to the version of `pandas`. `stocksDf = stocksDf.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(stocksDf), None)` may help.

Comment: @Huang Good answer!

Comment: @Huang Thanks you very much! it works for me!

Answer (score 4):

The article linked in the question is referring to DataFrame.to_sql() which you are not using in your code. If you want to maintain this way of writing to the database, you need to change the `NaN`s in your DataFrame:

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162723/replacing-pandas-or-numpy-nan-with-a-none-to-use-with-mysqldb), the solution is, to change all `NaN`-values to `None`:

```
stocksDf = stocksDf.where((pd.notnull(stocksDf)), None)
```

Further important annotation from the original answer:

This changes the dtype of all columns to `object`.

Comment: thanks, I've been struggling with this some error for the all afternoon. Your code fixed my error.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas read_csv function can put (at least) two types of nulls into your data, `numpy.float64('nan')` and `numpy.nan`.  There are cases where one is acceptable and the other isn't.  This sounds like one of those cases.  Use the debugger to determine what the `type()` of the data is.  You can then 'fix' the data with (`DataFrame.replace`)[http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace]

Answer (score 1):

Your data might have newline characters or **escape sequences** anywhere. This is considered as 'nan' by MySQL. So manually adjust such a situation or use another pieces of code from pandas to remove **escaped characters**

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this error too.
NaN was assigned to a Double variable if it was calculated in a function that divides by zero.
When attempting to store this value to the database it returns that error.
Solution:

Add an if clause before dividing by zero:

```
if (value2 = 0) then
{CalValue = 0}
else
{Calcvalue = 20/value2}
```