# Pandas to_sql() to update unique values in DB?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

How can I use the `df.to_sql(if_exists = 'append')` to append ONLY the unique values between the dataframe and the database. In other words, I would like to evaluate the duplicates between the DF and the DB and drop those duplicates before writing to the database.

Is there a parameter for this?

I understand that the parameters `if_exists = 'append'`  and `if_exists = 'replace'`is for the entire table -  not the unique entries.

```
I am using: 
sqlalchemy

pandas dataframe with the following datatypes: 
    index: datetime.datetime <-- Primary Key
    float
    float
    float
    float
    integer
    string <---  Primary Key
    string<----  Primary Key
```

I'm stuck on this so your help is much appreciated. -Thanks

Comment: You are doing upsert, maybe you can refer to my question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905337/how-to-use-pandas-to-do-upsert-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In pandas, there is no convenient argument in `to_sql` to append only non-duplicates to a final table. Consider using a staging temp table that pandas **always** replaces and then run a final append query to migrate temp table records to final table accounting only for unique PK's using the `NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)

df.to_sql(name='myTempTable', con=engine, if_exists='replace')

with engine.begin() as cn:
   sql = """INSERT INTO myFinalTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
            SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3, ...
            FROM myTempTable t
            WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT 1 FROM myFinalTable f
                 WHERE t.MatchColumn1 = f.MatchColumn1
                 AND t.MatchColumn2 = f.MatchColumn2)"""

   cn.execute(sql)
```

This would be an ANSI SQL solution and not restricted to vendor-specific methods like `UPSERT` and so is compliant in practically all SQL-integrated relational databases.

Comment: This was a great solution to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding!

Comment: actually would love to get your follow-up thoughts: it appears that I am still getting some duplicate errors. If my primary keys are, say 'Date', 'Instrument', 'Timeframe'. Then would those be the only columns in the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" argument? My script seems to be crashing on duplicates stil :-/

Comment: Those three columns will need to be added in the subquery of the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause to replace *MatchColumn#*.

Comment: do we have to manually create the `myTempTable`?

Comment: if myTempTable exists, it is replaced. If not it is created. Also, don't forget to commit the connection at the end.