# Bulk update to selective columns in postgresql using sqlalchemy and df.to_sql() method

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using postgresql where on daily basis I have to `UPDATE` the values of selective columns. My source is in pandas `df`. Since there are more than 1000 rows in `df`, I am using `df.to_sql()` method by `sqlalchemy`.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
df.to_sql(mytable,con=engine,if_exists='replace')
```

But there is a problem I am facing. Every time I use the above code snippets, it actually `DROP` the existing table in DB, then `CREATE` a new table with the column names as given in `df`. Which means the column names are getting changed!! Besides, total number of columns in `df` is less than that of in `mytable` in DB.

I have gone through [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188446/pandas-to-sql-to-update-unique-values-in-db) but I am not kind of looking this sort of solution.

Is there any other way to tackle this situation? Or is there any way to `UPSERT` row wise values into selective columns of database table? (like `for row,index in df.iterrows():`)

Comment: you are passing `if_exists='replace'` to the `to_sql()` method, that's why it create a new table for you. What behavior do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Louis Ng: I know that `if_exists=replace` shall exhibit the behaviour you are referring. i want the table in db to remain intact. Only the selected fields in that table should get updated with values from the dataframe. Column names should not change.