Programatically pass primary_key in SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL insert_on_conflict_nothing method
I'm trying to insert several Pandas DataFrames to corresponding PostgreSQL tables, each with a different Primary Key. I've attempted to implement the following method according to the documentation:
def insert_on_conflict_nothing(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    # tableIndex is the primary key in "conflict_table"
    data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    pkey = [pk_column.name for pk_column in table.primary_key.columns.values()]
    stmt = insert(table.table).values(data).on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=pkey)
    result = conn.execute(stmt)
    return result.rowcount

and then pass it on in a function:
def insert_workouts(workouts_df):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://' + db_user + ':' + db_pass + '@' + db_host + '/' + db_name)
    workouts_table_columns = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM fitness.workouts WHERE 1=2', engine).columns.to_list()
    workouts_df.columns = workouts_table_columns
    workouts_df.to_sql(
        name='workouts',
        schema='fitness',
        con=engine,
        if_exists='append',
        index=False,
        method=insert_on_conflict_nothing
    )

This, however, results in the following error: AttributeError: 'SQLTable' object has no attribute 'primary_key'.
Can anyone help me figure out a way to check the respective table's primary key (in my case, it will always be one column, if that matters), so that I don't have to hard-code it in multiple methods?
Thanks!
EDIT: I did some exploration/testing:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData
meta = MetaData()
tbl = Table('workouts', meta, schema='fitness', autoload_with=engine)
print(tbl.name)
pkey = [pk_column.name for pk_column in tbl.primary_key.columns.values()]
print(pkey)

which produces the correct output:
'workouts'
['workout_id']


Your guess is as good as mine. I took that snippet straight from the Pandas documentation. I'll add more testing examples in the post above.

The variable table is of type SQLTable, which is a pandas adapter class, (see source), not an sqlalchemy class.
However, the answer is on the next line:
    stmt = insert(table.table).values(data).on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=pkey)

you need to refer to table.table instead of just table. table.table is an actual sqlalchemy.Table, so changing your code to this should work.
    pkey = [pk_column.name for pk_column in table.table.primary_key.columns.values()]


I tried that before posting here. With this change, executing the insert_workouts() function results with the following error: SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: ...99AD05-3A55-46F9-990E-F451606F0A5F') ON CONFLICT () DO NOTHI..., and there's a ^ symbol below the right parenthesis after ON CONFLICT.

OK, so I added print(pkey) in the insert_on_conflict_nothing() method and when I ran the whole thing, I got [], so no primary key. Any idea why? As far as I can understand, the table parameter is passed by the insert_workouts function, so there should be no problem accessing its metadata.

Strange. The only difference to your exploratory testing in pandas should be that instead of meta = MetaData() they have meta = MetaData(schema=schema). What happens if you change your test to do the same?

Not sure I understand, but I did this in the tests: meta = MetaData(schema='fitness') and I got the correct primary key.

I found a workaround in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70808838/3133018.
