# pandas DataFrame.to_sql and nan values

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use pandas DataFrame.to_sql to insert values in a table of my Postgres database. I have some nan values in a column of integers that does not belong to any constraint.

I get the following error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (DataError) integer out of range
```

When I substitute nan values with zéros, insertion happens as wanted, so it is really nan values that are to blame for my error.

I have tried converting nan values to None and to np.nan , but I get the same error.
So the question is: what nan format do I need so that pd.to_sql handles it correctly?

My restrictions are : python 2.7 pandas 0.14.1 , sqlalchemy 0.9.8 , Postgres 9.2

Comment: similar problem here: "Incorrect decimal value: 'NaN' for column XYZ". XYZ in my case is a DECIMAL column.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your pandas version: 0.14.1.

> Starting with pandas 0.15, to_sql supports writing NaN values.

You can try upgrading your pandas.

Also, for now you can convert `NAN` to `NONE` like:

```
df = df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can unfortunately not upgrage pandas since it is on a server I use, and the administrator does not wish to proceed to an upgrade.. I have already tried replacing by None but it won't work, I get the same error..

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353732/python-pandas-write-to-sql-with-nan-values).