# Change default NULL values in pandas to_sql function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataframe with float columns, some values in which are NaN. I would like to write this dataframe to a snowflake database using the simple df.to_sql() function provided by pandas.

Here is the issue: snowflake [only accepts](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html) NaN (not NULL) as a float value. to_sql(), on the other hand, tries to uses the value NULL when it constructs the sql statement as mentioned [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353732/python-pandas-write-to-sql-with-nan-values).

I don't see a way to override how to_sql tries to pass null values to the database in the [docs for the to_sql function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Can this value be overwritten (for FLOAT columns, specifically)? Otherwise I will probably have to manually construct these sql statements.

Comment: I'm not clear on the requirement. The float type in Snowflake supports both NaN and NULL values.

Comment: Have you looked at the write_pandas() function in Snowflake Python connector?  Are you already using the `pd_writer` value in your to_sql() method?  Either might handle NaN and NULL better for you.