# Handling nulls with df.to_sql() in postgres

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sql-null

I have data that I am using `df.to_sql()` on to get into my postgres warehouse. I have used the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353732/python-pandas-write-to-sql-with-nan-values) to handle the same error, but now all nulls are inputted as `nan` in my tables. Below is how I implemented the answer and some things that I have done that do not work.

Looking for any suggestions here, running into this with text columns

```
df = df.apply(
            lambda col: col.astype(str).str.replace("\x00", "")
            if col.dtype == "object"
            else col,
            axis=0,
        )

# added these before .to_sql()
# .replace({"": None})
# .fillna(np.nan)
# .replace({np.nan: None})

df.to_sql(name, con, schema, if_exists="append")
```

Comment: Add some dummy sample data and desired result, also what's the structure of target table "name" in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @PepeNO not sure how this worked but I slapped a `.replace('nan', np.nan)` before the to_sql and it worked